# how to display bootstrap-alert height to smaller font, using bootstrap classes?

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, bootstrap-4

I have set alert after clicking delete-button.
but its default height is bigger and I wanted to make it smaller(height).

I tried [`display-4`](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.1/content/typography/) property, but it didn't worked.
I have set width to half of sceen by `w-50`, but half height of alert doesn't work as `h-50`.

`<div class="offset-3 alert alert-danger display-4 w-50  ">`

is there any class, like sm, xs to make alert small, like we use it in 
`<button class="btn-sm">`?

Comment: can you show more from your code and create fiddle

Answer (score 8):

Add `p-1` class to it, the large size  is due to padding in the alert. Reduce it by using `p-1` utility class of bootstrap. It will reduce the padding to 4px;

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-Gn5384xqQ1aoWXA+058RXPxPg6fy4IWvTNh0E263XmFcJlSAwiGgFAW/dAiS6JXm" crossorigin="anonymous">


<div class="alert alert-danger p-1">
  Small alert
</div>

<div class="alert alert-danger">
  Normal alert
</div>
```

Comment: thanks Nandita, but I already tried same your solution, by adding padding `p-0`.

Comment: Worked great and saved me time. Using BS5...

Answer (score 3):

Learn here about spacing in bootstrap-4:https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.0/utilities/spacing/

```css
.myAlert{
height: 59px!important;
}
```

```html
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.0/css/bootstrap.min.css">
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.14.0/umd/popper.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.0/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>


<div class="container">
  <h2>Alerts</h2>
  <p>Using p-0 means padding:0 learn in bootstrap spacing</p>
  <div class="alert alert-success p-0">
    <strong>Success!</strong> This alert box could indicate a successful or positive action.
  </div>
  
   <p>Set height in css with !important to prevent override</p>
  <div class="alert alert-success myAlert">
    <strong>Success!</strong> This alert box could indicate a successful or positive action.
  </div> 
  </div>
```

Answer (score 0):

I wanted an alert to be about the size of a btn, so I created the following CSS class for this use case:

```
.alert-btn-height {
    padding: .475rem .25rem !important;
}
```

You can similarly modify to match your desired formatting.